# Different views on a library

Tags: list, permissions, list-view, view, library

I have two questions regarding views of a doc library.

1. How can I restrict one of the views to be viewed by specific people?
2. How can I disable the views from the ribbon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How can I restrict one of the views to be viewed by specific people?**

**Unfortunately**, there is no way to manage permissions for **Views** as OOTB in SharePoint.

**Workarounds**

1. Using the **Target Audience.**

   - Create a page with a Library view, Edit the Library view
   - Specify your default view.
   - At the Target Audience, set the groups that you need to only see this view
2. Using 3rd Party tools Like info wise.

---

**How can I disable the views from the ribbon?**

You can hide the Views section in the ribbon using the below CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-cui-tabBody li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

> **Note:** add the above CSS in Script editor web part in the same page that you need to hide the Views section

Comment: FYI, the CSS in script editor is for SharePoint classic only 

Comment: Thank you so much I did it using the target audience and it works @MohamedEl-QassasMVP

Comment: @Arwa Glad to hear it helped you!